Confusion around role of alias in signing .aab file
I'm trying to update my app so I've created a new .aab file. When I went to sign my new .aab file with jarsigner it said that alias name was already in use, so I used a new one (alias_namev2) and signed the app. However, when I try to upload my new aab file to my app in the Google Play console I get an error that the signing keys don't match.
Is this because I used a different alias name? Should I sign the file again, this time with the same alias name? If so, how do I get past the error that said I couldn't sign it because I was trying to reuse the same alias name?
